# problem with hyperref-pdfpages interaction addtotoc at chapter-level

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages

I'm using the following code to insert a pdf as an appendix:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
text
\appendix
\phantomsection
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,0,{Common Parameters},mylabel}]{mypdf}

\end{document}
```

I get the `\ignorespaces` command in the toc (from the aux):

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {appendix}{\chapternumberline {A}\ignorespaces Common Parameters}{287}{appendix.A}}
```

which hyperref doesn't like (from the log):

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding)
```

So I looked at pdfpages.sty and saw the line where the `\ignorespaces` gets in

```
\AM@toc@title{\ignorespaces #4}%
```

I hate changing a package, but if I remove the tag, I have no problems that I can see.

This seems to only happen when I want the toc entry at the chapter level since this (section level) works okay:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,section, 1,{Common Parameters},mylabel}{mypdf}
```

What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A preliminary analysis is that the problem originates in the use by `pdfpages` of a `toks` register `\AM@toc@title`, and the expansion of its contents is delayed due to use of `\the`, then the mechanism of hyperref for handling `\ignorespaces` (`\let\ignorespaces\HyPsd@ignorespaces`) done in `\pdfstringdef` is broken due to that. (I admit I have not traced things to the bottom here, it is just from a quick look followed by a very wild guess).

Here is brutal "get rid of"

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\AM@parse@toclisti#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6\END{%
  \def\AM@toc@page{\AM@trim@space{#1}}%
  \def\AM@toc@section{\AM@trim@space{#2}}%
  \def\AM@toc@level{\AM@trim@space{#3}}%
  \AM@toc@title{#4}% remove \ignorespaces to please hyperref
  \def\AM@toc@label{\AM@trim@space{#5}}%
  \AM@checkinteger{\AM@toc@page}%
  \ifAM@integer\else
    \PackageError{pdfpages}
         {Missing number.\MessageBreak
          Page number in option `addtotoc' is not a number}
         {See the pdfpages manual for explanation.}%
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\tracingmacros1

\chapter{one}
text
\appendix
\phantomsection
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,0,{Common Parameters},mylabel}]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Note though that obviously `pdfpages` did the `\ignorespaces` because `#4` is a delimited argument hence may have a leading space. Thus don't use a leading space in `{Common Parameters}`.

There are ways to remove leading spaces which could be incorporated into `pdfpages`, or better, `pdfpages` could add hooks to use whatever pleases hyperref. (perhaps use some `\texorpdfstring` somewhere ?)

Anyway, the warning about ignoring `\ignorespaces` is only an innocuous warning.

More problematic is that any token in `#4` (the place occupied by your `{Common parameters}` will likely cause similar problem.

---

Edit:

Perhaps this could be used

```
\makeatletter
\def\AM@parse@toclisti#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6\END{%
  \def\AM@toc@page{\AM@trim@space{#1}}%
  \def\AM@toc@section{\AM@trim@space{#2}}%
  \def\AM@toc@level{\AM@trim@space{#3}}%
  \AM@toc@title\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#4}%
  \def\AM@toc@label{\AM@trim@space{#5}}%
  \AM@checkinteger{\AM@toc@page}%
  \ifAM@integer\else
    \PackageError{pdfpages}
         {Missing number.\MessageBreak
          Page number in option `addtotoc' is not a number}
         {See the pdfpages manual for explanation.}%
   \fi
}
\makeatother
```

as it will swallow one leading space token from `#4`.

This is just a simple-minded thing which will have its shortcomings.

---

With package `xinttools` you can help `pdfpages` remove space tokens without `\ignorespaces`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xinttools}
\makeatletter
\def\AM@parse@toclisti#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6\END{%
  \def\AM@toc@page{\AM@trim@space{#1}}%
  \def\AM@toc@section{\AM@trim@space{#2}}%
  \def\AM@toc@level{\AM@trim@space{#3}}%
  \AM@toc@title\expandafter{\romannumeral0\xintzapfirstspaces{#4}}%
  \def\AM@toc@label{\AM@trim@space{#5}}%
  \AM@checkinteger{\AM@toc@page}%
  \ifAM@integer\else
    \PackageError{pdfpages}
         {Missing number.\MessageBreak
          Page number in option `addtotoc' is not a number}
         {See the pdfpages manual for explanation.}%
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\chapter{one}
text
\appendix
\phantomsection
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,0,{Common Parameters},mylabel}]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

---

Of course, there is much simpler trick to remove leading spaces:

```
\makeatletter
\def\AM@parse@toclisti#1,#2,#3,#4#5,#6,#7\END{%
  \def\AM@toc@page{\AM@trim@space{#1}}%
  \def\AM@toc@section{\AM@trim@space{#2}}%
  \def\AM@toc@level{\AM@trim@space{#3}}%
  \AM@toc@title{#4#5}%
  \def\AM@toc@label{\AM@trim@space{#6}}%
  \AM@checkinteger{\AM@toc@page}%
  \ifAM@integer\else
    \PackageError{pdfpages}
         {Missing number.\MessageBreak
          Page number in option `addtotoc' is not a number}
         {See the pdfpages manual for explanation.}%
   \fi
}
\makeatother
```

But then you face brace removal issues. Which may be unimportant (or not).

---

To illustrate my statement that the incompatibility is deep, consider this

```
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,0,{Common \textbf{Parameters}},mylabel}]{example-image.pdf}
```

then you will have `hyperref` complain about `\textbf`. In fact, put in fourth parameter any sort of token which normally `hyperref` knows how to handle in PDF bookmarks, and you will trigger the warning. Because the token is not expanded at the time `hyperref` has redefined it, and later on, hyperref sees it and complains. This is an issue to be fixed on the `pdfpages` package side.

Comment: In the hyperref manual there a bit about adding stuff to the bookmark parsing (which is the issue here, not the toc), perhaps one might get away with defining ignorespaces locally different in the bookmarks using that mechanism. (not at pc, so cannot test, but I just used it to fix a lot of similar issues)

Comment: @daleif `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` mechanism is inefficient here.

Comment: It for it works... Solved my problems with hyperref throwing away a lot of stuff. Adding modified versions of certain macros gave me the result I wanted and no warnings.

Comment: @daleif, `\pdfstringdef` already contains ` \let\ignorespaces\HyPsd@ignorespaces` but the `\ignorespaces` is hidden by `pdfpages` in a  `toks`,  and using `\the` in the `\edef` or `\xdef` leaves it there unexpanded, so the expandable `\HyPsd@ignorespaces` or any other definition is ignored, thus one would have to hook deeper into hyperref, which is what you seem to suggest. But I think  it is more of `pdfpages` responsability to issue `hyperref`-compatible code.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Guess there is a reason why this feature is marked experimental. I don't remember if we hacked it once for a PhD thesis. Nah, that hack was to be able to get unnumbered entries to the toc (bibliography from included articles).

Comment: @daleif I see, thanks for pushing me into looking at `pdfpages` documentation! (I had done it in the past, but never used so far the `addtotoc` feature)

Comment: Good round up. Anyone contacting the author? He's usually quite grateful for code suggestions, especially on good ways of doing stuff. Can toks be avoided here?